# Try-catch and print trace in elisp

Tags: elisp, emacs24

How can this javascript code sample for throw/catch error written using elisp?

```
throw new Error("Boom!!!")
catch(error){
    console.log(err.stack)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs Lisp distinguishes between *conditions*, a high-level object-oriented construct, and *non-local exits*, a low-level construct that allows exiting a scope prematurely.

Conditions are captured using `condition-case`:

```
(condition-case nil
    (error "Error!")
  (error (message "Caught error")))
```

Non-local exists are handled using `catch`:

```
(progn
  (catch 'catcher
    (throw 'catcher 42))
  (message "Caught .. or perhaps not"))
```

In general, you should use conditions if you wish to participate in Emacs' error handling protocols, and `catch`/`throw` if you only need to exit prematurely.

In order to compute a backtrace, you may use the function `backtrace`:

```
(catch 'catcher
  (throw 'catcher
    (with-temp-buffer
      (backtrace)
      (buffer-string))))
```

Comment: good one, tx. but can i add more forms (or) statements to the catch body.. like (catch 'catcher (throw 'catcher 42) (message "i am inside catch block"))

Comment: `catch` doesn't actually have a handler — after a call to `throw`, the flow of control simply exits the `catch` form. If you need to know, you'll have to test the return value manually.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you;re not saying anything about printing a trace. `(debug)` can do it, but is there a way to get the trace as a string?

Comment: Right, I've added an example of the use of the `backtrace` function.

Comment: Note that `C-h f catch` clearly explains how `catch` works.

Comment: Afaict, `(backtrace)` shows the stack down to where this function is called whereas the Javascript `error.stack` has the stack down to where the error actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
(condition-case ex
    (error "Boom!!") 
  ('error (backtrace)))
```

More information on dealing with errors in Emacs is available [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Handling-Errors.html).

Comment: You have an extra quote in there I believe.

Comment: This doesn't give the full stacktrace of the original error however.